# In minecraft when I break a block it doesn’t let me collect

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

If I break wooden stairs it won’t let me recollect them. The item disappears in survival. It happens for everything, if I kill a mob no xp drops as well as items. I can only get fishing to work. I use minecraft on ps4.

Comment: Is your inventory full?

Comment: Are you definitely playing in survival and not creative?